# How to resolve Rails, GeoRuby (and postgis/postgresql): NameError: uninitialized constant Point?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, georuby

when i am running the code on rails console as:
`Point.from_x_y(88.365805,22.543538)`

Then getting error as:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Point
```

Can anyone help me to remove this error?

I am running `require 'gems'` before running this code as:

```
require 'geo_ruby'
require 'geo_ruby/ewk'
```

Answer (score 3):

It's namespaced, so if you're using it rails instead of pure ruby, you need to call the full namespace of the class.  Your query will work if you call instead:

```
GeoRuby::SimpleFeatures::Point.from_x_y(88.365805,22.543538)
```